# iOS application crashes when trying to get device location - Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, exc-bad-access, clplacemark

I am fairly new to iOS development, so sorry if this question has an easy fix of which I am unaware.

So I am currently creating an application which requires the user's current location as an address.

So in the class header I made sure to include CLLLocationManagerDelegate:

```
class SignupViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate  {...}
```

Next I created an instance variable for the location manager:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

I also created the CLLocationManagerDelegate functions:

```
// MARK: CLLocationManagerDelegate functions

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    for location in locations {
        self.getLocationAddress(location)
    }
}

func getLocationAddress(location:CLLocation) -> CLPlacemark? {
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    print("-> Finding user address...")
    var placemark:CLPlacemark!
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in
        if error == nil && placemarks!.count > 0 {
            placemark = placemarks![0] as CLPlacemark
            print(location)
            if placemark != nil {
                print(CLPlacemark().toString(placemark))
            } else {
                print("Problem with data received from geocoder")
            }
        }
    })
    return placemark
}
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Error when updating location " + error.localizedDescription)
}

// MARK: Helper functions


func getLocation() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

I also have a function toString defined as an extension to CLPlacemark:

```
extension CLPlacemark {
func toString(placemark: CLPlacemark) -> String {
    var addressString : String = ""
    if placemark.ISOcountryCode == "TW" /*Address Format in Chinese*/ {
        if placemark.country != nil {
            addressString = placemark.country!
        }
        if placemark.subAdministrativeArea != nil {
            addressString = addressString + placemark.subAdministrativeArea! + ", "
        }
        if placemark.postalCode != nil {
            addressString = addressString + placemark.postalCode! + " "
        }
        if placemark.locality != nil {
            addressString = addressString + placemark.locality!
        }
        if placemark.thoroughfare != nil {
            addressString = addressString + placemark.thoroughfare!
        }
        if placemark.subThoroughfare != nil {
            addressString = addressString + placemark.subThoroughfare!
        }
    } else {
        if placemark.subThoroughfare != nil {
            addressString = placemark.subThoroughfare! + " "
        }
        if placemark.thoroughfare != nil {
            addressString = addressString + placemark.thoroughfare! + ", "
        }
        if placemark.postalCode != nil {
            addressString = addressString + placemark.postalCode! + " "
        }
        if placemark.locality != nil {
            addressString = addressString + placemark.locality! + ", "
        }
        if placemark.administrativeArea != nil {
            addressString = addressString + placemark.administrativeArea! + " "
        }
        if placemark.country != nil {
            addressString = addressString + placemark.country!
        }
    }
    return addressString
}
```

When I run my code everything seems to work fine initially, this is the output in the console:

```
-> Finding user address...
-> Finding user address...
-> Finding user address...
-> Finding user address...
<+40.10886714,-88.23303354> +/- 10.00m (speed 0.00 mps / course 0.00) @ 5/8/16, 11:34:22 PM Central Daylight Time
401 E John St, 61820 Champaign, IL United States
(lldb)
```

However, at the end it crashes with an (lldb)and displays the error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)
[image: Also it is displaying the error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)]

[image: Console Screenshot]

Not too sure as to why the app is crashing after printing the address.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Would you mind posting the error that appears in the console? Most likely something is `nil` and you tried to access it.

Comment: There was nothing else that appeared in the console. I have added a screen shot to my post.

Comment: Trying enabling NSZombies as per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode) post, which may give some errors that may help.

Comment: I enabled Zombie Objects, but the console still outputs the same error: nothing but (lldb).

Comment: Could you place a breakpoint at the start of that closure and walk though the lines one by one to see where it crashes?

Comment: Just tried that: here is the new console output http://imgur.com/fHi9lVp
There doesn't seem to be any new useful information this time around either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111370/discussion-between-kevin-rajan-and-iliketau).

Comment: delete the dervied data and try once

Comment: @KevinRajan please checkout my answer below

Comment: Consider that you can't return a placemark from the `getLocationAddress` method because `reverseGeocodeLocation` works asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

but i don't know which fix this,

Instead of calling the extension function as

> print(CLPlacemark().toString(placemark))

call it as like this,

> print(placemark.toString(placemark))

because there is a memory leakage problem. Now, Its not crashing.

Comment: Why are you calling `toString` anyways? `print()` should call `placemarks`'s `description` property.

Comment: @ILikeTau actully the questioners' intention is to convert the placemarks's value with certain properties in to a address string, so only he has created  a extention and printed the value